# Magnolia override i18n in Freemarker Renderer

Tags: freemarker, magnolia

We have the problem that by default single quotes in `i18n` are not escaped in the magnolia freemarker renderer. That leads to the problem that our `i18n` string is too early closed in the html. As a simple fix we want to extend the `i18n` function provided in the Freemarker Template.

I have seen that it is possible to override the freemarker renderer with a decorator in `decorations/rendering/renderers/freemarker.yaml` but it seems that the `contextAttributes` doesn't include `i18n`. So the question is where does `i18n` come from and how can I extend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sadly not very easy to extend the default i18n mechanism. You might experiment with remapping the `info.magnolia.i18nsystem.TranslationService` to your custom implementation via component mappings in the module descriptor.

However, it seems that i18n messages with single (or double) quotes work fine.

[image]

Comment: Yes the question was not optimally worded. The problem only exist when you use an i18n message as an html attribute, e.g. `<my-webcomponent image-alt-text='${i18m["imageAltText"]}'>` in that case the text attribute is ended too early when the i18n message includes a single quote.